# Placing an <h3> over a form/div

Tags: html, css

I've got this HTML code and i want to place an  above this but, whatever i am doing, it is always placed to left side of the form.

I know it's a very basic question but i am not that experienced in CSS. How am i supposed to do this? Is there a w3-class that will do this for me?

```css
.bookbox{
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 16px !important;
  box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.bookcard{
  margin-top: 120px !important;
  margin-bottom: 120px !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  clear: both;
}

.float-left {
  float: left !important;
}

.m-1 {
  margin: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookbox">
    <h3>I'd like this to place above the bookcard</h3>
    <div class="bookcard">
        <form class="w3-container" method="GET" action="{{config('app.PATH_TO_INDEX', '')}}/findCar">
            <div class="float-left m-1">
                <input type="text" name="Standort" list="Standorte" class="w3-input w3-border" placeholder="Standort">
                    <datalist id="Standorte">
                        <option value="example"></option>
                    </datalist>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left m-1">
                <input type="text" name="Startdatum" class="date w3-input w3-border" id="f0date" placeholder="Startdatum">
            </div>
            <div class="float-left m-1">
                <input type="text" name="Enddatum" class="date w3-input w3-border {{ $errors->has('Enddatum') ? 'border-danger' : '' }}" id="f1date" placeholder="Enddatum">
            </div>
            <div class="float-left m-1">
                <button type="submit" class="w3-button margin-small signalButton w3-hover-text-blue w3-blue-grey w3-hover-blue-grey w3-hover-opacity" id="submit0">Fahrzeug finden</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is no `<h3>` in your HTML code.

Comment: The default for `flex-direction` is `row`, if you want `column`, you need to explicitly specify it.

Comment: You can't place a `<h3>` over a div....

Comment: @xmaster Yes, you can...in several ways.

Comment: I Just want to have an <h3> on top and then my div below that

Comment: So create a demo **with** the `h3` and **show** us what the issue is.

Comment: yeah i did.....

Comment: flex-direction column won't do it, or i am doing it wrong

Comment: @Paulie_D do you have an idea what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `flex-wrap:wrap` to .bookbox and `width:100%` to bookcard